# How to play RTSP live video streaming in UWP app

Tags: uwp, rtsp, windows-10-universal, mediaelement

I want to play live video stream `RTSP protocol` using `MediaElement` in Universal Windows Platform (**UWP**) app platform.

I am trying to this way but it now working.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" />
```

Code Behind

```
var streamUri = new Uri("rtsp://X.X.X.X:1027/h264/ch1.2");  
var streamResponse = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync(streamUri);
if (streamResponse.Status == AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationStatus.Success)
{
   mediaPlayer.SetMediaStreamSource(streamResponse.MediaSource);
}
```

Error:

> **Got Status** => streamResponse.Status = ManifestDownloadFailure
>
> **Internal Error**
>   base =
>   {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00D36B2): The request
>   is invalid in the current state. The request is invalid in the current
>   state.    at
>   Windows.Media.Streaming.Adaptive.AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationResult.get_MediaSource()}

Is there any third party solution or another way video play in **UWP app**?

Comment: Please check with this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop/issues/14). That the FFmpegInterop can play the RTSP live video.